# How to see the actual row count for a postgres table in pgAdmin 4?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

pgAdmin4 has a nice menu option to count the rows of a table (see screenshot below).

[image]

However, when you choose it, it simply shows a green message box "Table Rows Counted". How can I access the actual row count?

[image]

Answer (score 17, accepted):

If you open (double click) the table: At the "main window", tab "Properties" you can see them:

[image]